# Knife tool not cutting

Tags: knife-tool

I messed something in my model and I cannot knife cut any geometry. If I move geometry to new file, it works. So it has to be some model settings that I tweaked and now Knife Tool does not cut. It can be activated but performs no cutting action. Can you recreate the problem?
Blender v2.9

Here's the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fLXuYrUpUXPpCjo2x_W5dnvBGlACInDV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: are you using the short cut ar the option in edit mode?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to share file and give link in question

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=v8LkPK6X" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/v8LkPK6X/)

Comment: SHikha Mittal, I tried both - "K" hotkey and button.

Comment: honestly , not able to figure out the solution

Comment: But you did manage to reproduce the bug in your computer?

Comment: I tried to do the knife thing both by hot key and the option but failed ,